# How to select a td within a selected tr object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used jQuery to select a table row for a particular player by doing the following:

```
var player_row = $("#player-row-"+p.player_id);
```

The `player_row` object is a reference to a `<tr>` element. The `<tr>` contains several `<td>` definitions, one of which has the markup `<td class="fp">5</td>` What's the best way using jQuery to access the `td` with class `fp` against `player_row` and change that `5` to a different value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use

```
 $('#player_row td.fb').text('newvalue');
```

Answer (score 1):

use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)/[children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) with [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) and then use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to change the value

```
player_row.children('.fp').text('newvalue')
```

Comment: `$('#tr0 .fp')` will save quite a few CPU cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without even creating an extra variable, use below

```
    $("tr#player-row-"+p.player_id+" td.fp").html(new_value)
```

This will select a `<td>` with class "fp" which must be under a `<tr>` element with id:

```
    player-row-<specified_player_id>
```

`html()` will set the value of required  element to new value.